# Deleting files with PowerShell script

Tags: windows, powershell, filesystems, prtg

I have a script in PowerShell that scans a directory of folders that are named with the following convention: yyyymmdd.  It scans the directory and finds all the folders that are current and up to one week old, then copies them over to another directory. After it copies them over to the other directory, I would like to have it delete the folders in the new directory which are named the same way and that are older than 18 months old.  Would there be an easy way to do this? I have pasted the script below.

```
$targetdirectory = "\\DPR320-W12-1600\PRTG"
$sourcedirectory = "C:\Users\Public\Documents\PRTG Traffic Grapher"
$todaysdate=get-date
$minusoneweek=$todaysdate.adddays(-7)
$minusdate=($minusoneweek.Month).tostring(),($minusoneweek.day).tostring(),($minusoneweek.year).tostring()
$todaysdatestring=($todaysdate.Month).tostring(),($todaysdate.day).tostring(),($todaysdate.year).tostring()
$oldfilename=$minusdate[0]+$minusdate[1]+$minusdate[2]+" backup"
$newfilename=$todaysdatestring[0]+$todaysdatestring[1]+$todaysdatestring[2]+" backup"


Get-ChildItem $sourcedirectory\config | Where-Object { 
    $_.PsIsContainer -and 
    $_.BaseName -match '\d{6}' -and 
    ([DateTime]::ParseExact($_.BaseName, 'yyyyMMdd', $null) -gt (Get-Date).AddDays(-7)) 
} |Copy-Item -Recurse -Force -Destination $targetdirectory\$oldfilename\config

Copy-Item -Force $sourcedirectory\config.csv -Destination $targetdirectory\$oldfilename
Copy-Item -Force $sourcedirectory\config.prtg -Destination $targetdirectory\$oldfilename

rename-item $targetdirectory\$oldfilename $newfilename
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your discussion with FoxDeploy:
This will loop through $YourDirectory and check if the name represents the date that's older than 18 months.
Used this for my own cleanup, except I have names in dotted format.

```
$CleanupList = Get-ChildItem $YourDirectory
$Threshold = (get-date).AddMonths(-18)

foreach ($DirName in $CleanupList)
{
    If (([datetime]::ParseExact($DirName.BaseName,'yyyyMMdd',$null)) -lt $Threshold)
    {
        Remove-Item $DirName.FullName -Force -Recurse
    }
}
```

Comment: I have folders in there that don't necessarily follow that name convention.  How would I make the script ignore them and only focus on the files that fit the name convention?

Comment: If you can supply a few examples to show the idea. So far I can only think of checking whether ParseExact was actually able to fetch the date from folder name.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `$targetDirectory` contains the files you'd like to remove (Those older than 18 months), just add this to the end of your script:

```
#resolve this day, 18 months ago
$18Months = (get-date).AddMonths(-18)

#get the name in the right format (i.e. 20141224)
$18MonthString = get-date -Date $18Months -UFormat "%Y%m%d"

#find the files with a name like this and delete them
$OldPrtgFiles = dir $targetDirectory | Where Name -like "$18MonthString*" 
$OldPrtgFiles | remove-item -whatif
```

The first execution will display the `-WhatIf` view, to show you which files would be removed.  If you're happy with this, remove `WhatIf`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! That would work, however, the write time would not be 18 months ago since some files, which are old data, were just recently copied to the directory.  How would I be able to tell which files to remove using the folder name?  The naming format is the date on which the data is taken so, for example, 20140624.  That would be the folder name for data taken on 06/24/2014.

Comment: Ah, I see.  So we would want to delete files with a name like 20141224 (18 months ago)

Comment: Got it, check my answer now.

Comment: Thanks! Just to clarify, will this delete all files 18 months and older or will it delete just the files that are 18 months old?

Comment: In our case, we're deleting files which are precisely 18 months old from today.  If you want to delete all files older than 18 months, change the logic to this `$OldPrtgFiles = dir $targetDirectory | Where BaseName -le "$18MonthString"  `